# How to change development port 3030 when I build and deploy to target server?

Tags: dart

I am facing a problem is dart editor using `3030` as default port.
My url always start from `http:// 127.0.0.1:3030 /xxxx` in my dart code.

So, I want to know any flexible can change my host/port setting in dart script when deploy it to different places?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly.
This is nothing you set in your Dart script unless your Dart script is the web server.
This is a configuration setting of the web server you are using.